# Python : How to reset index if a row matches a condition?

Tags: python, dataframe

My dataframe contains a column where value 'aa' repeats after every 3rd index.
I want to reset my index to 0 wherever it finds 'aa'.

Current Dataframe:

|  | name | loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | john | aa |
| 1 | popp | bb |
| 2 | lily | cc |
| 3 | fete | aa |
| 4 | bruh | gg |
| 5 | kiku | uu |
| 6 | kiku | aa |
| 7 | kiku | ur |

Expected output:

|  | name | loc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | john | aa |
| 1 | popp | bb |
| 2 | lily | cc |
| 0 | fete | aa |
| 1 | bruh | gg |
| 2 | kiku | uu |
| 0 | kiku | aa |
| 1 | kiku | ur |

and so on.....
I have tried below but it is not giving me the results.

```
if ('aa' in df['loc'].values):
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Really looking for some guidance as I am new to Python and unable to figure out the solution.

Comment: In general this is a "pandas question most likely and not vanilla python.  I also think the question isn't quite well formed.  Its not really clear what you're trying to accomplish (the code and the examples don't quite go together).  Maybe this section of the userguide will help though.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: @daidoji70 my code is not working  as expected and I guess its wrong hence, I have asked for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you**

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """name,loc
john,aa
popp,bb
lily,cc
fete,aa
bruh,gg
kiku,uu
kiku,aa
kiku,ur
"""

data = io.StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(data)

print(df)

   name loc
0  john  aa
1  popp  bb
2  lily  cc
3  fete  aa
4  bruh  gg
5  kiku  uu
6  kiku  aa
7  kiku  ur

df.index = df.index.where(df['loc'] != 'aa', 0)

lst = df.index.to_list()
ac = -1
for i, v in enumerate(lst[:]):
    if v == 0:
        ac = 0
        continue
    if i == 0 or ac < 0:
        continue
    ac += 1
    lst[i] = ac

df.index = lst

print(df)

   name loc
0  john  aa
1  popp  bb
2  lily  cc
0  fete  aa
1  bruh  gg
2  kiku  uu
0  kiku  aa
1  kiku  ur
```

Comment: what is ac here? could you please explain?

Comment: It sets the index value to 0 every time it finds the value 0 and increments it until another 0 is found. Then it starts again from 0.